# Omit html, body, head tags if there is a comment

Tags: html

I've been reading the W3C draft http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-body-element and it says:

> A body element's start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the body element is not a space character or a comment, except if the first thing inside the body element is a meta, link, script, style, or template element.
>   A body element's end tag may be omitted if the body element is not immediately followed by a comment.

First of all I must admit I've googled but I can't really understand this sentence fully, I'll analize how I see it:

You CAN omit the tag WHEN: it's empty, the first thing is NOT a space character or a comment. Then EXCEPT? So this also means when it is NOT `meta`, `link`, `script`, `style` or `template` aswell? Or it's alright if it's one of those tags? I jus't don't understand how the except is meant here, and that's why I went to the second step: trying to achieve an error in verification.

Based on the W3C draft about `head`, `body` and `html`, the smallest verified page is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Title</title>
```

But if I added a comment after the `<title>` it goes inside the `<head>` according to Chrome automatic filling which still validates the page.

So now I'm wondering, after I've tried several times, is it impossible to get a page which is not validated while omitting the tags because of the browser assumptions?

I know it's probably useless to wonder this stuff as I won't be omitting the tags anyways but I'm just wondering first of all what that except means (which is only present in the `body` omitting description, because in `head` and `html` it doesn't say). Then I'm wondering if it's true that I cannot get a not validated page by omitting tags due to the automatic assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's like this. A comment node can go inside the body element or outside it, as a direct child of the html element or a direct child of the head element. All are valid.

So suppose you wanted a comment to go as the first child of the body element. If you include the `body` start tag, you can write the comment immediately following that and everything is peachy.

But if you omit the `body` start tag, how do you get the comment to be the first child of the body element? You can't do it in mark-up, because the comment will go into the DOM as a direct child of either the `html` element or the `head` element. Hence, in this scenario, you can't omit the `body` start tag.

So it's not a matter of validity. Your mark-up is valid either way. It's just that you can't achieve the DOM structure you desire.

The other exceptions are analogous.

Another way of looking at it: It's normal for web authors to think about writing a web page in HTML mark-up and expect to to be parsed into a DOM. Here, the description is really about the opposite process, starting with a DOM and serializing it to HTML mark-up. Now suppose you are writing a serializer. You serializer encounters a body element and it wants to decide whether it can omit the body start tag. So it looks at the first child. If it's a meta element, a link element, a script element, etc., it knows that it must write out the body tag, because if it doesn't, when the HTML mark-up is re-parsed, that element will be added as a child of the head element, and not the body element where it began. That means that CSS selectors such as `body meta` might stop matching, and JavaScript that was searching for elements inside body would no longer find the element, when they did before the serialize/parse cycle.

Comment: I see, you gave me a point of view which i was missing (because i don't know JavaScript much and i was thinking mainly in HTML side) : i am reading the HTML draft, which means it's OK to omit for HTML, but by JavaScript side, it'll mess up the DOM which will make me hard (or impossible i suppose?) to access something inside the body because the browser assumption may not be what i want it to be. Right?

Comment: Your assumption of where the elements are in the DOM may be incorrect, yes.

Comment: Alright I think i understand now, in simple words, if one of those things above (comment,space,meta,etc) are written when body tag is omitted, the DOM will assume stuff after that aren't part of body, and if i tried to access with CSS stuff like body>p, it wouldn't work as the DOM wouldn't know that the paragraph i added after a comment would be part of the body. I saw that if i add a comment, it will automatically add it to the head, while if its a <p> it will be automatically in the body! Nice to know such knowledge! I think I know what i should know about this, there isn't more right?Thanks

Comment: A `<p>` element is not allowed inside `<head>`, so it will go inside the `<body>` element. The `<body>` element **always** exists, tags or no tags. Likewise, (non-empty) `<table>` elements **always** contain a `<tbody>` element, even if you didn't spells it out. This may be surprising the first time you try some DOM scripting. (Modulo browser bugs, of course.)

Comment: @NisseEngström - This is pretty off the subject, but there's a whole bunch of valid, non-empty tables that don't contain a tbody. For example, the table could contain a thead or a tfoot instead. It could contain a caption element, colgroup elements, script elements and template elements, none of which will cause a tbody element to be created.

Comment: @Alohci: I meant a table with a non-empty **body**. Note that in HTML4, the `<tbody>` element is not optional which it seems to be (I'm not sure) in HTML5.